# Is there a way to check the existence of a variable without producing an error, just return false

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, exists

**a is not declared**

```
try:
    a
except:
    pass
```

RESULT: test of a produces error which is runs except

```
if a in locals():pass
if a in globals():pass
```

RESULT: produces NameError

Is there a simple pre-built solution to return `True` / `False` based on whether the variable exists?

Comment: Variable name as a string `'a' in globals()`?

Comment: How about `if "a" in locals():pass` ?

Comment: What is the problem with `try: except [NameError]:`?

Comment: The real solution is, of course, to not get into this position in the first place. Make sure all variables exist unconditionally before they are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) return dictionaries that have string keys:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> locals()
{'__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 'b': 2, '__doc__': None, 'a': 1}
>>> globals()
{'__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, 'b': 2, '__doc__': None, 'a': 1}
>>>
```

Thus, you need to use strings for your tests:

```
if "a" in locals():pass
if "a" in globals():pass
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> "a" in locals()
True
>>> "x" in locals()
False
>>> "a" in globals()
True
>>> "x" in globals()
False
>>>
```

Comment: yep yep, ta very much.